# Extract values from soapenv envelope xml in php

Tags: php, xml, soap

i am new to XMl. i want to extract the status values in the following xml .i have no idea how to do that in php . this is a response that i ma getting from a API call.

```
<soapenv:envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:body>
    <savesalesorderresponse xmlns="http://www.smartturn.com/services/OccamService/sales-order">
    <uploadresponse>
    <ns1:externalrefid xmlns:ns1="http://www.smartturn.com/services/occamtypes">007</ns1:externalrefid>
    <ns2:status xmlns:ns2="http://www.smartturn.com/services/occamtypes">SUCCESS</ns2:status>
    <ns6:systemid xmlns:ns6="http://www.smartturn.com/services/occamtypes">SO-059241</ns6:systemid>
    </uploadresponse>
    </savesalesorderresponse>
    </soapenv:body>
    </soapenv:envelope>
```

solution code will be appreciated 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is Register namespaces with `registerXPathNamespace`

```
$xml = new  SimpleXMLElement($data);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("ns", "http://www.smartturn.com/services/occamtypes");
$status = $xml->xpath('//ns:status');
$status = (string)  $status[0];
print($status);
```

Output

```
SUCCESS
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: using simpleXMl function of php i am not getting its functionality ..solution code with this xml will be appreciated